# Selenium - Java - How to implement XML variables

Tags: java, selenium

I am setting up a Selenium automated testing system written in Java.

I have the following structure:

```
src/
  modules/
     LoginForm 
  browsers/
     Chrome
     Firefox
```

This application has to be able to test multiple websites with different username and passwords etc..

I do not want to have to go into each of the classes in order to change the parameters (e.g. if we have to change the website and/or the username and password). I'm therefore wondering if it's possible to have an XML file that we can store all of these values in that then can be read at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create a file with all the parameters and load them at run time. Then you can pick each value within the loop: For example

```
       public void read(File file) throws IOException{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            line=scanner.nextLine(); 

             //Split the line to get the variables
              //pass variables to selenium object at each line:
    }
  }
```

That way you will be able to get the job done

Comment: Hey, thanks! Is there a way to store it inside a global object? I can then use `customSettings.webSite`?

Comment: probably you need to do this. You define an object, load all the values in to it, then have a mechanism to go the the next set. Or else you can use an List of objects. When you load data you can create objects then at run time point them by position. eg `customsettings=listItems.get(position).website`

Answer (score 0):

There are several frameworks to read XML files. You can create a XML file as follows and read it.

You may also use a properties file 
data.properties

A scanner also works fine. So, now you have many options. Go do it. :)